# app for saving a path made of X and Y coordinates of an image in TXT

Tags: image, coordinates, line, imagemap

i need to draw a path on top of an image, just by drawing many points, and than have to save the X and Y coordinates in order in a file
(exactly like [this website](https://www.mobilefish.com/services/record_mouse_coordinates/record_mouse_coordinates.php))

[image]

but i need a more "usable " app/program/website than the one i found. because i need to be able to zoom, and possibly deleading and moving points more easily, do you know anything that can work?

Comment: Geogebra maybe? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ikyrzLozC8 http://draw.io maybe?

Comment: it's better that the website that i was using, so thank you. i won't get the question as solved because i still hope to find something better